# XMLHttpRequest - Wait for document to be ready before request.onload

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am in the process of developing a night mode/dark theme for a local old school forum website.
Applying only the CSS is not enough, because the images have a light stroke around them, so the images need to be replaced in the Document as well.

To do this I run this code in my Chromium extension:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(["darkMode"], (res) => {
    if (res.darkMode === true) {
        var avalehtLogo = {
            selector: "selector", 
            img: chrome.runtime.getURL("assets/images/logo_transparent.png")
        };
        
        //placeholder until we make our changes
        var placeholder = document.createElement("html");
        placeholder.style.backgroundColor = "#1D2226";
        document.replaceChild(placeholder, document.children[0]);

        //catch the request
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", document.URL);
        request.responseType = 'document';
        request.onload = function() {
            if(this.status == 200) {
                //modify the document
                this.response.children[0].children[1].querySelector(avalehtLogo.selector).src = avalehtLogo.img;
                for (var replacableItem in imagesToReplace) {
                    this.response.children[0].children[1].querySelectorAll(imagesToReplace[replacableItem].selector).forEach(function(node) {
                        node.src = imagesToReplace[replacableItem].img
                    });
                }
                //add the document back
                document.replaceChild(document.adoptNode(this.response.children[0]), document.children[0]);
            }
        };
        request.send();
    }
})
```

The extension logic works fine: dark mode is applied/un-applied on demand and images are replaced etc.

However, I have encountered an issue... After the dark theme is applied, some of the JS functions cannot be executed:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: storeCaret is not defined at HTMLTextAreaElement.onclick
```

I compared the original (light theme) document with my modified (dark theme) document and found, that some JS scripts in the <head> tag are not loaded in for the dark theme.

**Dark theme HTML**

```
<script src="/templates/scriptaculous.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Original HTML:**

```
<script src="/templates/scriptaculous.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://x.y/templates/builder.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://x.y/templates/effects.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://x.y/templates/dragdrop.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://x.y/templates/controls.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://x.y/templates/slider.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://x.y/templates/sound.js"></script>
```

So, my suspicion is, that the document is caught too early and the JS scripts are not yet loaded in the document. If that truly is the case, then my question is:

How do I ensure, that the document is completely loaded before I modify it?

I tried investigating the console and network tab, but I cannot figure out when these scripts are added or why these scripts are not added when dark mode is applied...

Comment: Probably because you replace the entire document and you do not include scripts. You probably are breaking a lot of stuff. Seems odd you are not just replacing the images on the page itself and adding a new stylesheet.

Comment: This is not how it's done. 1) Remove XMLHttpRequest and simply use MutationObserver. 2) Remove chrome.storage.local.get and use chrome.scripting.registerContentScripts in the background/popup script instead of `content_scripts` in manifest.json to register/unregister the script when the global switch is toggled and specify runAt: 'document_start'.

Comment: @wOxxOm I am adding the Stylesheet via scripting.registerContentScripts, but that is not enough since images need to be replaced. How to replace images then?

Comment: Use the same registerContentScripts to register a content script `js`. This is what my comment was about.

Comment: @wOxxOm the same code is also being run as a content script and it is declared so in the manifest with the parameter document_start.

Comment: Please read my comment again. It says you should remove `content_scripts` from manifest.json and use registerContentScripts instead.